# ADO.Net Connection Pooling with an MSSQL Account that is Disabled

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

In our production environment we have a database that every 30 minutes is restored from a vendor's log shipping backup. When that restore happens, our SQL Auth account is disabled, the database is restored and the account is re-enabled.

A problem occurs when the connection pool is fresh and we attempt to connect to the disabled account. The bad connection is then pooled (I assume) and for the next 1 to 3 hours every connection throws a SQLException `[SqlException: Login failed for user 'xxxxx'. Reason: The account is disabled.]`

Even though, we can connect to the database via SSMS and an Application Pool reset fixes the issue.

Is there any fix other than to disable pooling?

Comment: Are you looking for [`SqlConnection.ClearAllPools`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.clearallpools(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: That is a maybe, I can try an get that into production.